# If A is a closed linear subspace of a vector space X (which may not be Hilbert) is it true that $A^{\perp} = 0 \Leftrightarrow A = X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, inner-products

If A is a closed linear subspace of a vector space X (which may not be Hilbert) is it true that $A^{\perp} = 0 \Leftrightarrow A = X$?

$A^{\perp} = \{x \in X|\langle x,a\rangle=0, \forall a \in A\}$. Obviously, we have if $A = X$, then $A^{\perp} = 0$. Is the other direction (i.e. $A^{\perp} = 0 \Rightarrow A = X$) right?
 (Notice that $X$ may not be a Hilbert space.)

If it is not right, could you please provide a counterexample?

Comment: Since you say "closed" linear subspace, you should specify the topology on $X$.

Comment: @uniquesolution Just consider $X$ as any vector space. We can use the norm induced by the inner product defined on $X$ to measure distance in $A$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ is the space of all sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of real numbers such that $n\gg0\implies x_n=0$, if$$\left\langle(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\right\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n,$$you can take$$A=\left\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in X\,\middle|\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x_n}n=0\right\}.$$Then $A\neq X$. And $A$ is closed, since it is the kernel of a continuous map. But $A^\perp=\{0\}$. In fact, if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in A^\perp$, then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is orthogonal to each of the following sequences:

- $(1,-2,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$;
- $(1,0,-3,0,0,0,\ldots)$;
- $(1,0,0,-4,0,0,\ldots)$

and so on. But this means that $x_1=2x_2$, $x_1=3x_3$, $x_1=4x_4$, … Since $x_n=0$ if $n\gg0$, this implies that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is the null sequence.

---

Note that $X$ is a subspace of $\ell^2$. If $X$ was the whole space $\ell^2$, then my definition of $A$ would still make sense and $A$ would still be closed, but it would not be true anymore that $A^\perp=\{0\}$. In fact, then we would have $A^\perp=\left\langle\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\right\rangle$.

Comment: What is the topology on $X$?

Comment: Why does $A^{\perp} = \{0\}$?

Comment: @uniquesolution It is the topology induced by the norm $\lVert(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\rVert=\sqrt{\left\langle(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\right\rangle}$.

Comment: @U2647 I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: I believe $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is orthogonal to $(1, 1,0,0,0,...0), (1,0,1,0,...)...$

Comment: @U2647 Why do you say that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, I made a mistake. You are right. Thanks!

Comment: @uniquesolution Why is that so?

Comment: @uniquesolution That result is about another concept of $A^\perp$. If there is something wrong in my answer, please tell me where the error is. Then I will either correct it or delete my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - I don't understand what is this "another concept of $A^{\perp}$" you are referring to. The OP explicitly states that the topology is induced by a norm induced by an inner product, so that the space under discussion is a pre-hilbert space, and there are no non-trivial subspaces in a pre-hilbert space on which all non-zero continuous functionals vanish.

Comment: @uniquesolution Because “your” $A^\perp$ is a subset of $X^*$, whereas “my” $A^\perp$ is a subset of $X$. On the other hand, “your” $A^\perp$ is is defined for every normed vector space, whereas “my” $A^\perp$ only makes sense in the case of vector spaces endowed with an inner product.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are right. The natural embedding of $X$ into $X^*$ in your example is not onto, exactly because it is only a pre-Hilbert space, and not a Hilbert space. Thank you for clarifying that point.

Comment: @uniquesolution I have added another paragraph to my answer in an attempt to make that point more clear.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It seems that the formulation of the question itself is not sufficiently accurate. When the OP writes "Just consider any vector space", it is quite misleading, because what he really means is a very special inner-product space, which is not complete.

Comment: @uniquesolution I fully agree.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a normed space, and $A^{\perp}$ is understood to be a subspace of the dual space $X^*$ (i.e., continuous linear functionals on $X$), then the only closed subspace $A$ such that $A^{\perp}=0$ is the entire space $X$, because of the following general result:

> Let $X$ be a normed space and $Y$ a subspace of $X$. A vector $x$ belongs to the closure of $Y$ if and only if
>   every bounded functional that vanishes on $Y$, also vanishes at $x$.